# When table has expanded vertically to its maximum height - make element pop up in next table cell-column

Tags: html, css, html-table, height, multiple-columns

I am working on a page, where I currently have 12 title placed in a menu. I have used a table to layout the projects. Upon clicking one element/project the table expand vertically and displays a project description.

I wish to set a max-height property for the overall table, so that it is only able to expand until a certain point. So whenever the overall height of a table-column, determined by the sum of both "opened" and "closed projects, exceeds a certain height, the element jumps to the next column in the table, where it can continue to expand downwards. Basically as if it functioned like a regular column in a grid.

Here's some code

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#Project1").click(function(){
                $("p.Describtion1").toggle();
              });
            });

        </script>



</head>



<body>

<table id="content">
    <tr>
        <td id="Project1">
                Wer Baut Der Stadt 2019
            <br>
                <p class="Describtion1" style="display:none;">
                Identity and Font developed for the lecture series on architecture conducted by No Image in Berlin. 
                </p>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>2019</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

[image]

```
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#content td {
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-height: 500px;
}

#content td:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 18%;
}

#content td:nth-child(even) {
  width: 7%;
}


  #Project1:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: default;
    }


p {

display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
font-size: 15px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this:

```
#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 500px;
}

#content td {
     display: flex;
     flex-grow: 1;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately this did not work, all it did was expanding the first column even more.

Comment: Can you send me what this code did and an example of how you want it done? @CarinaThornval

Comment: Sure! with "example of how I want it done" do you mean like a mockup, or? Do you want the code or without the alterations you suggested? To where should I sent it? :)

Comment: I'd be very happy if you could send me the mockup :) @CarinaThornval

Comment: Sure! To where should I sent it? I can't find any inbox or alike, where I can direct the mock up to.

Comment: I wrote you a private message on facebook! :)

Comment: Super - it's coming soon!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood, you have a row where you want content to be layed into columns and filling them one after one.  content of a tag, will not 'jump' into next tag, but columns CSS might mimic it .

example with a few comments where you can tune value or find out the purpose

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Project1").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* reset , optionnal */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* =====================*/
/* config  setting size */
/* =====================*/

#content {
  min-height: 20em;
  max-height: 500px;      /* here your max-height */
}

article {
  min-height: 4em;         /*but still, here set a min height that suits your needs */
  column-width: 250px;     /* here set width of your columns */
  column-rule : solid 1px; /* if you need a border in between columns */
}
.Describtion {
  display: none;/* or not if you want to see them on load */
}
/* =====================*/
/*      end config      */
/* =====================*/


h1 {
  font-size: inherit;/* 30px * 1.6em made it too big here */
  cursor:pointer; /* make it obvious it is clickable */
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow-x: hidden;/* let the row scroll instead */
  overflow: auto;/* maybe not tall enough for every entry */
  margin: 0 1em;
}

article {
  flex: 1;/* size them evenly */
  overflow-y: hidden;/* make wrap content into columns */
  overflow-x: auto;/* it might expand past the viewport, make this one only scroll */
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;
}

.Project1:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: default;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align:justify
}


/* push content to fill first column before wrapping to next */
.Describtion:after {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">

  <article>
    <h1 class="Project1">some title</h1>
    <div class="Describtion">
      <p> tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </article> <article>
    <h1 class="Project1">some title</h1>
    <div class="Describtion">
      <p> tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </article> <article>
    <h1 class="Project1">some title</h1>
    <div class="Describtion">
      <p> tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1 class="Project1">some title</h1>
    <div class="Describtion">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1 class="Project1">some title</h1>
    <div class="Describtion">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

about column CSS :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for this it is much appreciated!